# Spawn Event when Barcode is Scanned

Tags: c#, event-handling, barcode-scanner

Im making an inventory application using c#.  The application needs to be driven by the Barcode scanner ie. every time a barcode is scanned, I need an event to be spawned to take the necessary action. I am using a USB barcode scanner.  I have tried using a TextChanged event in a text box, but this spawns an event for each character in the string, rather than one for the whole string. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scanner, you should be able to have it append a new line character after each scan.  Then you can have a `KeyPress` event that waits for a newline before consuming the barcode.